# Moore's law: relationship between transistor count on an integrated circuit and minimum feature size

Tags: integrated-circuit, microchip, microprocessor

I'm doing a project about Moore's law, looking at physical limits of the technology / materials we're using (photolithography for example), the limit you'll come to is the minimum feature size.

For this project I also have to establish a model, I've done so in mathematica, but since we're following Moore's law it's a pretty simplistic model that just doubles the transistor count of a base year every two years.

My question is: is there a strong relationship / conversion (possibly from data) between minimum feature size and the transistor count on an integrated circuit?

Answer (score 1):

As a simple approximation, transistor count is determined by the number of transistors per unit area so it is inversely proportional to the area required for a single transistor. The area required is proportional to the square of the linear dimension. The feature size is a linear dimension, to the increase in transistors per unit area is proportional to the square of the feature size. Decrease the feature size to 70% of its original value and you double the number of transistors per unit area.